# Python: Matplotlib.pyplot works with jupyter notebook but doesnt work with VS Code .py scripts

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Recently I came across this error where `import matplotlib.pyplot` works in jupyter notebook just fine but when I create a test.py with same code and try to run it in VS Code I get the error shown in the picture. I'm using fresh install of anaconda 4.6.7 with python 3.7 and I'm also using conda base environment on both jupyter and also VSCode to run my scripts.

[Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqXSA.png)

[VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV4m2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,thanks anyways.I just needed to enable running scripts in power shell and that fixed my problem.Do not know why that was a problem in the first place.I am new to stack overflow do i need to close or delete this question,someone lead me in the right direction.